# Faster implementation for the conversion of variable length json file to pandas dataframe

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to import a json object in python. The json object is converted to a dictionary. Since the dictionary has variable length, I am not able to use pandas.DataFrame.from_dict() operation on such dictionary.

Based on the problem already answered in this forum, I tried using:

`df=pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in detection.items()})`

However, when the size of dictionary increases to 40000 or 60000, this operation takes a while to convert the dictionary to a pandas dataframe. My experiments with a dictionary of size  11000 takes 10 seconds and with size of 37000 takes 30 seconds.

I would like to ask if there is any faster implementation of such procedures which can be utilised for **big dictionaries**.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the in-built methods `read_json` or `from_dict` in pandas?

Comment: `from_dict` throws a value error: arrays must all be the same length.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801119/how-to-convert-nested-json-structure-to-dataframe/58801340?noredirect=1#comment103904288_58801340 can resolve your query. Hope it helps..!!